# vmware workstation 16 cannot drag and drop or see shared folders w centos8 guest

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I just installed VMWare Workstation 16.1 on my Windows 10 desktop and build a CentOS 8 guest. Guest has the latest VMWare Tools installed via yum (open-vm-tools and open-vm-tools-desktop 11.1.0.2). I cannot drag and drop nor see/mount any shared folders, stuff that used to work just fine on older versions of vmware and linux guests. Cut&Paste DOES work fine for text.

Guest Isolation has both drag&drop and copy&paste enabled. Shared Folders is always enabled and I have a share mapped to a local windows folder.

In my process list on the guest I see vmtoolsd is running - and systemctl reports it is running as well. I know it is running because my display size & scaling work fine and cut & paste text works.

In my user's home folder I have a hidden folder .cache/vmware/drag_and_drop/xxxxxxx. That folder is symlinked to into /tmp/VMwareDnD/.

Some other things...

```
ls -l /usr/bin/vmware-user-suid-wrapper 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 13080 Jul 21 18:48 /usr/bin/vmware-user-suid-wrapper
```

and /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/cl-root     /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=f1501a12-1fe4-466c-9d27-485fdc12e3aa /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/cl-home     /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/cl-swap     none                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

I disabled selinux.

I'm running out of things to check... any advice appreciated!!

Comment: I fired up an older CentOS7 VM I had, where I confirmed drag&drop still worked, and upgraded the vmware tools via YUM to the new 11 version, and drag & drop still worked. So that means the problem is probably specific to CentOS 8. Still testing